# Android sensors becoming uncalibrated

Tags: android, android-sensors

I'm having trouble with an augmented reality application I'm writing and specifically the sensors I'm listening to in two different activities.

I'm using the accelerometer and magnetometer to determine the devices orientation. I do this in two activities.

When using the one activity, the orientation (specifically the azimuth) is determined fine but when using the other activity with the exact same procedure provides results indicating that the sensors are uncalibrated. If I then calibrate the sensors in this activity, the sensors seem uncalibrated in the previous activity.

What could I be doing wrong? I'm registering and unregistering them correctly as described in the API.

Comment: How are the results differing exactly?

Comment: The azimuth readings differ in that looking in the Westerly direction, one activity receives readings near to 270 (degrees) whilst the other is far off. Moreover, I implemented a small compass arrow to point in each north, south, east and west directions and these don't move properly as I rotate the phone whilst in the camera view the directions remain correct.